# Standard ubuntu 15.04 won't boot, but ubuntu (upstart) does

Tags: boot, startup, cinnamon, systemd

I understand that Ubuntu switched to `systemd` recently from `upstart`.
Ubuntu started on the first boot, I installed cinnamon and made a change to `grub.cfg` in attempt to get my USB 3.0 Ports working, making me thing that the `grub.cfg` change is the culprit.
Now I need to select `Ubuntu with linux [version] (upstart)` to get it to boot.
I can provide any logs/lshw/[whatever]. I just want to get Ubuntu working normally.

Comment: What changes did you make? Did you make changes to `grub.cfg` or `gedit /etc/default/grub` and then properly update GRUB `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question should be closed, I have set the default grub option to upstart and that worked for me as a workaround. Anyways it's been so long that I've switched my OS 3 times.